# How to calculate the Grand Total of all the prices located in sub-total section?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ajax

There is a table of products having quantity price and subtotal, I just want to calculate grand-total of all the subtotal prices and show in grand-total section, sub-total price are in  section having class name "total". I tried to sum-up of all the sub-total price but the result show "0.00" on the grand-total section. here is the table look like:
[image: here is the table look like]

Code:

```
<?php

include("includes/db.php");

$object   = $_GET['dist'];
$items = json_decode(($object), true); 
$itemIds = [];
foreach( $items as $item){
    $itemIds[] = $item["id"];
}
$idstr = implode(" ,", $itemIds);
$query = "SELECT id, product_title as name ,price FROM products WHERE id IN ($idstr)";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) ;
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><th>Name</th><th>Price</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Sub Total</th></tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
echo "<tr> ";
    echo "<td>" .  $row["name"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .  $row["price"] . "</td>";
    $quantity = null;
    $subtotal = null;
    foreach($items as $key => $item){
        if($item["id"] == $row["id"]){
            $quantity = $item["quantity"];
            $subtotal = $quantity * $row["price"];
            $items[$key]["price"] = $row["price"];
            $items[$key]["subtotal"] = $subtotal;
        }
    }
    echo "<td>" . $quantity . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='total'>" .  $subtotal . "</td>";
    echo "</tr> ";
}
echo "</table>";
echo "<h2 id='grandtotal'></h2>";
?>
</body>
</html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
// // Grand Total
function grandtotal() {

var sum=0;
$('td.total').each(function(){
var item_val=parseFloat($(this).val());
if(isNaN(item_val)){
  item_val=0;
}
sum+=item_val;
console.log(sum);
$('h2#grandtotal').text(sum.toFixed(2));
});

}
</script>
```

Comment: Provide sample of rendered html. Doesn't look like you ever call `grandtotal()` anywhere

Comment: Doing it in php looks a lot simpler to me.

Comment: @charlietfl I call the function inside the body onload

Comment: @msg How can i sum all the sub-total?

Comment: @msg It can show me error
Undefined variable: total in C:\xampp\htdocs\Online Quotation Generator (FYP)\reciept.php on line 70

Comment: But return me the accurate answer, now issue is how can i resolve this error message ? @msg

Comment: @msg Its Working Thanks Aloot :)